# How to generate graph on a slide in PowerPoint on Macintosh?

Tags: excel, office365, powerpoint

**Issue Description**: To generate a graph on a slide. In PowerPoint on Macintosh shapes.addchart or shapes.addchart2 methods are not defined.

**Solution Tried**: Generate chart dynamically on embedded Excel then paste it on slide. It is giving out of memory error.

**Expected Resolution**: An alternative to shapes.addchart method or some other work around to achieve the target.

Windows
OS: Windows 10 Pro Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.693)
Office: Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus, Version 1611 (Build 7571.2109)
PowerPoint: PowerPoint 2016 MSO (16.0.7571.7095) 32 bit

MAC
OS: macOS Sierra, Version 10.12
Office: Office 365
PowerPoint: Version 15.30(170107)

**Code Snippet**:

```
Dim myChart As Chart
'xlLine=4
Set myChart = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddChart(Type:=4).Chart
```

**Error Message**:  “Method or data member not found”

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to maintain a library of pre-made charts in a separate Powerpoint file. Open this file windowlessly, copy the needed chart, paste it into the desired slide in your target presentation, then close the "hidden" chart presentation.